# JMeter authentication problems

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In Jmeter when I do a load test I download a document in the application but the result is viewed as "You cannot open this document because no login server has been detected". However I'm able to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your test plan and carefully expect all preceding responses, most likely you have to authenticate prior to downloading

Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your Test Plan and re-run the test. If it doesn't resolve your issue you might have to perform some correlation to handle mandatory dynamic parameters or bypass [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection or whatever.